# Spark worker containers terminate with Command exited with code 1 [ not able to connect to local PC]

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a spark cluster setup on docker. using a openjdk:8-alpine. I am running it on local. **Local pc name is DESKTOP-PCH5L6D**

I am able to submit jobs but the error I see at the worker docker container is
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: DESKTOP-PCH5L6D

local pc is on Win 10 Pro.

Am new to docker and seeking help as to how to approach to solve for this.
docker compose file am using to create the local spark cluster

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  spark-master:
    image: cmishr4/spark:latest
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    volumes:
      - ./../share:/share
    privileged: true
    networks:
      - spark-network
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077"
      - "SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080"
    command: "sh start-master.sh"
  spark-worker:
    image: cmishr4/spark:latest
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - ./../share:/share
    privileged: true
    networks:
      - spark-network
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
      - "SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=8080"
    command: "sh start-worker.sh"
networks:
  spark-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

scala class main method:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .appName("sample")
  .master("spark://localhost:7077")
  .config("spark.executor.cores", "1")
  .config("spark.executor.memory","1g")
  .getOrCreate()
val csv = spark.sparkContext.textFile("C:/Users/chand/wrkspcs/sparkws/share/input")
val rows = csv.map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
val header = rows.first
val data = rows.filter(_(0) != header(0))
val rdd = data.map(row => Row(row(0), row(1).toInt))

val schema = new StructType()
  .add(StructField("name", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("age", IntegerType, true))

val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
spark.stop()
```

log from the main class

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/05/27 02:25:55 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.3
19/05/27 02:25:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/05/27 02:25:55 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: sample
19/05/27 02:25:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: chand
19/05/27 02:25:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: chand
19/05/27 02:25:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/05/27 02:25:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/05/27 02:25:56 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(chand); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(chand); groups with modify permissions: Set()
<b>19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 53511.</b>
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\chand\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-c4f6d60f-c867-4c52-895d-111030c92193
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 4.1 GB
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://DESKTOP-PCH5L6D:4040
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://localhost:7077...
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:7077 after 27 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20190527062557-0000
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 53553.
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on DESKTOP-PCH5L6D:53553
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, DESKTOP-PCH5L6D, 53553, None)
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20190527062557-0000/0 on worker-20190527062533-172.18.0.3-44351 (172.18.0.3:44351) with 1 core(s)
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20190527062557-0000/0 on hostPort 172.18.0.3:44351 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager DESKTOP-PCH5L6D:53553 with 4.1 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, DESKTOP-PCH5L6D, 53553, None)
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, DESKTOP-PCH5L6D, 53553, None)
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, DESKTOP-PCH5L6D, 53553, None)
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20190527062557-0000/0 is now RUNNING
19/05/27 02:25:57 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 214.6 KB, free 4.1 GB)
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 20.4 KB, free 4.1 GB)
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on DESKTOP-PCH5L6D:53553 (size: 20.4 KB, free: 4.1 GB)
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at App.scala:24
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: first at App.scala:26
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (first at App.scala:26) with 1 output partitions
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (first at App.scala:26)
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at App.scala:25), which has no missing parents
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.6 KB, free 4.1 GB)
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.2 KB, free 4.1 GB)
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on DESKTOP-PCH5L6D:53553 (size: 2.2 KB, free: 4.1 GB)
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1161
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at App.scala:25) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
19/05/27 02:25:58 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
19/05/27 02:25:59 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20190527062557-0000/0 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
19/05/27 02:25:59 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20190527062557-0000/0 removed: Command exited with code 1
19/05/27 02:25:59 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20190527062557-0000/1 on worker-20190527062533-172.18.0.3-44351 (172.18.0.3:44351) with 1 core(s)
19/05/27 02:25:59 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20190527062557-0000/1 on hostPort 172.18.0.3:44351 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
19/05/27 02:25:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 0 requested
19/05/27 02:25:59 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
19/05/27 02:25:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 0 from BlockManagerMaster.
19/05/27 02:25:59 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20190527062557-0000/1 is now RUNNING
19/05/27 02:26:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20190527062557-0000/1 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
19/05/27 02:26:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20190527062557-0000/1 removed: Command exited with code 1
19/05/27 02:26:01 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 1 from BlockManagerMaster.
19/05/27 02:26:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 1 requested
19/05/27 02:26:01 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 1
19/05/27 02:26:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20190527062557-0000/2 on worker-20190527062533-172.18.0.3-44351 (172.18.0.3:44351) with 1 core(s)
19/05/27 02:26:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20190527062557-0000/2 on hostPort 172.18.0.3:44351 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
19/05/27 02:26:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20190527062557-0000/2 is now RUNNING
19/05/27 02:26:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20190527062557-0000/2 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
```

from the worker container I see the job fails with the following exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-PCH5L6D:53511
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: DESKTOP-PCH5L6D
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
```

Comment: - 1 : Check the cluster : When you access the Master UI on 8080, Are you able to see the master address and the active workers ? 
- 2 : Can you give the spark-submit command that you run ?

Comment: In the service that you want to connect to your host, add an "extra_hosts" block like this: "extra_hosts: - "DESKTOP-PCH5L6D:<host_ip>". This should enable the service to see your host with the name you want. The host_ip is the IP of your host on the local network.

Comment: adding the extra_host mapping actually resolved the issue. ty

Answer (score 0):

added the additional parameter extra_hosts to fix the issue as shown below

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  spark-master:
    image: cmishr4/spark:latest
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    volumes:
      - ./../share:/share

    privileged: true
    networks:
      - spark-network
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077"
      - "SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080"
    command: "sh start-master.sh"
  spark-worker:
    image: cmishr4/spark:latest
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - ./../share:/share

    privileged: true
    networks:
      - spark-network
    extra_hosts: 
        - "DESKTOP-PCH5L6D:10.0.75.1"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
      - "SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=8080"
    command: "sh start-worker.sh"
networks:
  spark-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
```